# error: unrecognized arguments in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have a problem with Jenkins settings
I need to change string parameter Default Value: "Erie-M10" to "HDP-2.5.1.0 (Erie-M10 Azure)"
It is name of the version in Jira.
When I changed it, I have an "error: unrecognized arguments: (Erie-M10 Azure)"
I thought that it is issue with space or brackets and tried to use screening '  and \  and '\' but nothing changed((
Please help me.
Here is an screen-shot in attachment [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ2oE.png)

Error text:
`+ python UT/utreport.py -configfile /grid/0/jenkins/.ssh/hwx_secrets.conf -dbName 2.5-maint -version HDP-2.5.1.0 '(Erie-M10' 'Azure)' -OS Linux usage: utreport.py [-h] -configfile CONF_FILE -dbName DBNAME -version VERSION -OS OS utreport.py: error: unrecognized arguments: (Erie-M10 Azure) Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure [INFO] HipChat notification sent to the following rooms: RE-notifications Finished: FAILURE`

Answer (score 0):

You should find a step which starts this python script, it may be "Execute shell" step. Use double quotes around `version` variable, i.e.

```
python UT/utreport.py -configfile ${param1} -dbName ${dbName} -version "${version}" -OS Linux
```